# Linear Layout Embeded in Another Linear Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to embed a linear layout in another linear layout.  I have a map view.  If I put embeded layout AFTER mapview it does not work.  If I put it BEFORE it does?  Why and what should I do?

Two files given below: first one fail. second one works?  I want the first one though.

```
<!--two files.  

The first file does not work.  The Check Boxes in an embeded linear layout is below the mapview.  It only shows map view.  

The second file works.  The Check Boxes in an embeded linear layout is ABOVE the mapview.-->

<!-- FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE FILE ONE-->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#A971E5" >


    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapWhenImClose"    
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0MbR34udiEJdnkplC1F7rK4ZxbSFzdRagCruFDA"/>
        <!--  had this line but it said depreciated        
        android:enabled="true" -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkShowStreetView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/strShowStreetView" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkShowSatelliteView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/strShowSatelliteView" />

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>


<!--File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two File Two-->


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#A971E5" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkShowStreetView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/strShowStreetView" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkShowSatelliteView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/strShowSatelliteView" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapWhenImClose"    
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0MbR34udiEJdnkplC1F7rK4ZxbSFzdRagCruFDA"/>
        <!--  had this line but it said depreciated        
        android:enabled="true" -->

</LinearLayout>
```

http://pastebin.com/Tfsec1Mh

Comment: Logically it seems the `MapView` is taking up the full screen because you have `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` and it's forcing the `LinearLayout` off the bottom of the screen. What happens if you set its height to `wrap_content` instead? Alternatively put the `MapView` in a `LinearLayout` of its own, set the height of that to 0dp and the same for the `LinearLayout` which holds the `CheckBoxes`. Then set `android:layout_weight` on each to allocate a proportion of the screen.

Comment: sorry just noticed this...ill play with that approach too...my main goal right now is learning more than just getting something out the door.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MapView` covers the whole screen with `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapWhenImClose"    
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0MbR34udiEJdnkplC1F7rK4ZxbSFzdRagCruFDA"/>
        <!--  had this line but it said depreciated        
        android:enabled="true" -->
```

**Edit:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#A971E5" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/thebar" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkShowStreetView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/strShowStreetView" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkShowSatelliteView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/strShowSatelliteView" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapWhenImClose"    
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/thebar"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0MbR34udiEJdnkplC1F7rK4ZxbSFzdRagCruFDA"/>
        <!--  had this line but it said depreciated        
        android:enabled="true" -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I think that's the right direction however when I make this change I notice in the designer the map becomes a thin sliver.  When I run it in an AVD it looks the same (map takes up screen and don't see check boxes).

Comment: Can I add a screenshot to this?  I don't see anywhere to upload a file.

Comment: I understand the check mark for the correct answer but what is the up/down numbers for?

Comment: @TheArchitect See if my edited xml helps. You can add images with the image tag in the bar at the top(which you'll see if you edit the question). If the answer is helpful/unhelpful you can upvote/downvote it and the owner you'll get/lose some reputation points from this.

Comment: Ok sweet thanks bro that works!  of course the map shoulda came first but i understood what you were saying.  :-) thank you again